# Meteor Mongo find with filter options

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I would like to run a mongo find but also have it filter. $and makes every object required and $or shows results for any of the matching object but still does not filter.

This is my current query

```js
var query = {
  organizationId:user.organizationId,
  formName: this.props.formName,
  $or:[
    {producerId:this.props.producerId},
    {blockId:this.props.blockId},
    {created:{$gte:new Date(this.props.startDate), $lt:new Date(this.props.endDate)}}
  ]};
```

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking for. Are the `props` optional? Can you give an example of the expected output for a sample input?

Comment: @DavidWeldon the props are just values IE producerId:'t45454sdfdedfdf'

Comment: @DavidWeldon if I use $or as long as one of the parameters matches then it returns docs. For example form name "almog" and producerId "Y" it returns doc but if I run the find with producerId "X" it still shows the pervious results as the form name still matches. I want to filter out if there is no producerId with X value